# Combine two or more arrays of different size to one array at compiletime

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

I was not able to find an answer on how to combine two or more arrays at compiletime in modern c++.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

const std::array<std::uint8_t, 1> one_elem = {1};
const std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> two_elem = {2, 3};
const std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> all = {one_elem, two_elem}; 
// expected: all == {1, 2, 3}
```

I would be glad with anything that is somewhat easy to read, e.g.

```
std::uint8_t one_elem[] = {1};
std::uint8_t two_elem[] = {2, 3};
std::uint8_t all[] = {one_elem, two_elem}; // cannot be that hard
```

Is there a way? What can I do to get this solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using C++17, you can do this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
constexpr std::array<T, N1 + N2> concat(std::array<T, N1> lhs, std::array<T, N2> rhs)
{
    std::array<T, N1 + N2> result{};
    std::size_t index = 0;

    for (auto& el : lhs) {
        result[index] = std::move(el);
        ++index;
    }
    for (auto& el : rhs) {
        result[index] = std::move(el);
        ++index;
    }

    return result;
}

constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 1> one_elem = {1};
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> two_elem = {2, 3};
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> all = concat(one_elem, two_elem);
```

It doesn't work in C++14, because `std::array` isn't constexpr friendly until C++17. However, if you don't care that the final result is `constexpr`, you can simply mark each variable as `const`, and this will work:

```
const std::array<std::uint8_t, 1> one_elem = {1};
const std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> two_elem = {2, 3};
const std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> all = concat(one_elem, two_elem);
```

The compiler will almost certainly optimize the `concat` away.

If you need a C++14 solution, we have to create it via `std::array`'s constructor, so it's not nearly as nice:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

// We need to have two parameter packs in order to
// unpack both arrays. The easiest way I could think of for
// doing so is by using a parameter pack on a template class
template <std::size_t... I1s>
struct ConcatHelper
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t... I2s>
    static constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(I1s) + sizeof...(I2s)>
    concat(std::array<T, sizeof...(I1s)> const& lhs,
           std::array<T, sizeof...(I2s)> const& rhs,
           std::index_sequence<I2s...>)
    {
        return { lhs[I1s]... , rhs[I2s]... };
    }
};

// Makes it easier to get the correct ConcatHelper if we know a
// std::index_sequence. There is no implementation for this function,
// since we are only getting its type via decltype()
template <std::size_t... I1s>
ConcatHelper<I1s...> get_helper_type(std::index_sequence<I1s...>);

template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
constexpr std::array<T, N1 + N2> concat(std::array<T, N1> const& lhs, std::array<T, N2> const& rhs)
{
    return decltype(get_helper_type(std::make_index_sequence<N1>{}))::concat(lhs, rhs, std::make_index_sequence<N2>{});
}

constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 1> one_elem = {1};
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> two_elem = {2, 3};
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> all = concat(one_elem, two_elem);
```

Comment: Perhaps this is possible. What do you suggest to make it fit for more than two arrays?

Comment: Note that `3` can be `one_elem.size() + two_elem.size()`, as `array::size` is `constexpr`.

Comment: @vsoftco And you can always declare it as `constexpr auto all = ...`

Comment: @Justin Yes, probably the best way.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Just use `concat(first, concat(second, third))`. Or if you really want it to look like `concat(first, second, third)`, the variadic version is easy to write in terms of this

Comment: So there is no somewhat easy way to achieve that in c++ 14? And I have to runtime combine them, despite they are all const(expr)? Right now I think about the "static ctor" inner class replacement that can be done in c++.

Comment: This is really fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: You could also just not use the `constexpr`, and the first solution works fine in C++14. You don't use `constexpr` in your question.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I guess that's true; the compiler would probably optimize it away. I guess I got slightly carried away, but having it be `constexpr` is a nice benefit

Comment: Great idea! Is there any possibility to implement something like `append`, I just don't want to introduce the 3rd variable, there are some application scenarios

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I don't follow what you mean. What do you mean by "3rd variable"? What should `append` do differently from `concat`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear， just something like `one_elem.append(two_elem)`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin We can't add methods to existing types. But you could just write `concat(one_elem, two_elem)`

Answer (score 6):

There's already a way to concatenate arrays in C++: [`std::tuple_cat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat). The only problem is that it gives you a `tuple<uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t>` instead of a `std::array<uint8_t, 3>`. But that problem is solvable with a different standard library function: [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply). That one is technically C++17, but is implementable in C++14. You just need a funject:

```
struct to_array_t {
    template <class T, class... Ts> 
    std::array<std::decay_t<T>, sizeof...(Ts)+1> operator()(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) const {
        return {{std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}};
    }   
} to_array{};
```

and then you can use it:

```
auto all = std::apply(to_array, std::tuple_cat(one_elem, two_elem));
```

Which might be easier to just hide behind a function:

```
template <class Target=void, class... TupleLike>
auto array_concat(TupleLike&&... tuples) {
    return std::apply([](auto&& first, auto&&... rest){
        using T = std::conditional_t<
            !std::is_void<Target>::value, Target, std::decay_t<decltype(first)>>;
        return std::array<T, sizeof...(rest)+1>{{
            decltype(first)(first), decltype(rest)(rest)...
        }};
    }, std::tuple_cat(std::forward<TupleLike>(tuples)...));
}
```

Perfect forwarding with lambdas is a bit ugly. The `Target` type is allow the user to specify a type for the resulting array - otherwise it will be selected as the decayed type of the first element.

Comment: One really strong benefit of this approach is that it is general: it works for more than just a `std::array`. You could `array_concat` a `tuple<T, T, T>` and an `array<T, 5>` just fine. It is also variadic easily, as it uses `std::tuple_cat`